# Removing titlebar from Qt window while keeping the default window borders

Tags: c++, qt, window

I'm trying to remove the default Windows titlebar from my Qt window (QT version 5.12.2 and using C++) while still keeping the window borders. I've more or less achieved this using the flag `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint`. However, this changes the window borders to white lines instead of the default borders.

Example of how the borders look AFTER I've applied the `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` flag:
[image]

As you can see, these are not the normal Windows window borders.

How can I change/edit these boders (i.e. change their color) or how am I able to keep the default Windows window borders while removing the titlebar?

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    launcher mainWindow;

    //debugChecks();
    mainWindow.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle("Test");
    mainWindow.show();

    return application.exec();
}
```

launcher.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPoint>
#include "ui_launcher.h"

class launcher : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    launcher(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::launcherClass ui;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* eventVar);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* eventVar);
    int mouseClickX = 0;
    int mouseClickY = 0;

};
```

launcher.cpp

```
#include "launcher.h"

launcher::launcher(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);
}


void launcher::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* eventVar) {

    mouseClickX = eventVar->x();
    mouseClickY = eventVar->y();
}

void launcher::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* eventVar) {
    move(eventVar->globalX() - mouseClickX, eventVar->globalY() - mouseClickY);
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added one. Please let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description isn't really clear. One should not be using a QMainWindow for a logon/in dialog. Having said that I created an application on Ubuntu 20.04 (should build fine for you as I used qmake). You can [download the project zip here](https://www.logikalsolutions.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/StackOver1.zip). When the application starts it looks like this:

[image]

After clicking on "golden" it looks like this:

[image]

After Green it looks like this:

[image]

After clicking on Freaky it looks like this:

[image]

Please note that FramelessWindowHint not only removes the title bar and system menu along with window frame, *it also removes your ability to resize/drag/move the window*.

My apologies for not taking out the StackOver1.pro.user file. Didn't think about it until just now. You will need to delete that or it could hose your build.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out using your answer! I'm new to GUI development, so may I ask why it's not good to use QMainWindow for login? I wanted to use `stackedWidget` to switch between pages on this window.

Comment: Set yourself up a Ubuntu 20.04 VM under Oracle VirtualBox. Get Qt and PostgreSQL installed for development. Build and test source code for this project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xpnsqt/

Answer (score 0):

```
QPalette and QStyle for Border
```

Palette Can Change window styles and colors of the Application. and for Reference
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qtwidgets-widgets-styles-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
self.setWindowTitle("‎") # Python
```

‎

```
mainWindow.setWindowTitle(""); # C/C++
```

but instead of passing an empty string, pass an empty character. This one worked for me: https://emptycharacter.com/